# Pull and embed code from within a div on another page

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple-html-dom to try and pull some code from another site. Here's some simple example code that replicates what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Title!</h1>
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="another_class">...</div>
        <div class="one_more">
          Some awesome text!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="another_class">...</div>
        <div class="one_more">
          Some awesome text!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="another_class">...</div>
        <div class="one_more">
          Some awesome text!
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I'm trying to pull all div sample blocks...including the tags. So basically I want to echo the following code onto my site, tags and all:

```
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="another_class">...</div>
        <div class="one_more">
          Some awesome text!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="another_class">...</div>
        <div class="one_more">
          Some awesome text!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sample">
        <div class="another_class">...</div>
        <div class="one_more">
          Some awesome text!
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just learned about simple-html-dom today, so I'm still trying to figure it out. Here's what I've gathered so far, which isn't working.

```
<?php
  include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
  $page = 'http://www.sampleURL.com';
  $html = file_get_html($page);
  foreach($html->find('div.sample') as $element) 
    echo $element->outertext . '<br />';    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem...I was attempting to pull from the wrong URL >_>

No wonder it wasn't returning anything! The code I have posted is correct.